# Cordova password encryption

Tags: javascript, cordova, encryption

I have done some research on encryption and learnt how it works and what it consists of but I'm yet to fully understand how to implement password encryption.

I'm trying to encrypt my passwords that are being sent to my database, how can I achieve this?

Thanks to the information you guys provided I have had a look at hash tables, am I correct in assuming a hash table basically converts a value to a different value for example:

> var HashTable = { one: [1,10,5], two: [2], three: [3, 30, 300] }

and then passes the new value to the database?

Comment: The first and most important thing to know is, you should never *encrypt* passwords, you should *hash* them - the difference being that encryption implies you have a way of *decrypting* them, but *hashing* means you can only compare the input and say if it matches, without ever being able to get back the original.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys I do appreciate it, let me see what I can find on hashing and how to implement it =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not encrypt passwords, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key.

Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

[Cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) are substantially more sophisticated than the example in the question, their output can not be distinguished from random bits/bytes, a one bit change on the input essentially causes 50% or the output bits to change and they are not reversible.

Comment: Thank you Zaph really appreciate the help great answer.